# Strange situation: text from MainActivity being shown in every fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, textfield

I'm new here and I'm writing this question, because I'm making my first application for Android devices. I use Android Studio, of course. My problem is:

I have got a strange situation: I have a TextVield with a kind of welcome to the user in MainActivity, which is shown when the app starts and when I'm using the hamburger menu to navigate to other fragments in my app, the text from MainActivity is visible in every fragment. Hamburger itself works right. What can I do to fix this issue?

Here are parts of my code - I think the crucial ones, but I'm not 100% sure, because I'm quite new to Android and Java.

This comes from MainActivity.java:

```java
public void selectedtMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment mfragment= null;
    Class fragmentClass;

    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.main:
            fragmentClass = main.class;    
            break;
        case R.id.menu:
            fragmentClass = menu.class;    
            break;
        case R.id.galery:
            fragmentClass = galery.class;  
            break;
        case R.id.contact:
            fragmentClass = contact.class;  
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = main.class;   
    }
    try
    {
        mfragment= (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                                                            
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContent, mfragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mlayout.closeDrawers();

}

private void setContent (NavigationView navigationView)
{
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
        {
            selectedtMenuItem(item);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This comes from activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nawigacja"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="#303F9F"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And perhaps AndroidManifest.xml would be useful:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.menu_boczne">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Activity in your case it's view container for fragments content, so all what you'll put into activity layout, will be displayed in each fragment layout. You can control your TextView's visibility, or remove this from activity layout and add to the specific fragment layout.

Comment: add background color on your  Hamburger Fragment will resolve your issue. also do not forget to set onClickable =true on your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly simple: what you are doing is adding fragment to the `ConstraintLayout` that you have. It does not remove `TextView` you have, rather just adds fragment's UI elements after it.

What you should do to retain your design:

1. Add another element, `FrameLayout` will do, after that `TextBox` and move your id `fragmentContent` to it from your `ConstraintLayout`

   ```xml
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/welcome"
           android:layout_width="300dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/fragmentContent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
2. Make transaction towards it, just like you are already doing:

   ```java
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContent, mfragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
   ```

Comment: Actually it hasn't helped. What do you suggest?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by that. The fragment will be replaced inside a dedicated container by the hint I've provided, thus won't overlap with your `TextView`. What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but to be honest I quite don't understand what do you mean (because I'm really new to this). I thought about creating a fragment inside this MainActivity, and put the welcome text in it. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @The_Long_Distance_Runner Yes it will be. A good approach is to keep your activity just for the purpose of changing between fragments and not having any actual content. I would do it this way: create a fragment which will be your default one and replace it right away inside `onCreate` of your activity. Then put your `TextView` inside this default fragment and you should be good to go. Pro tip: the element you want to perform transaction on (first argument in `replace`) should be `FrameLayout` as it's the lightest layout for the app to render

Comment: Well, I think I understand the concept, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've created a fragment and added it statically to the activity, but the problem is still present. Is this because of the fact I added the fragment statically?